# Spreading data in multiple tables in MySQL database?

Tags: mysql

Im writing an application that have 1000 objects and around 10 million lines of data. The data will be used to plot a chart containing more than 1000 values each time its plotted. Does it helps the application performance if I create 1 table for each object and have their data spread across all the tables instead of the same one?

Im afraid the application will slow down searching the 1000 values inside a 10 million lines table, specially when joining other two or three tables.

Is there a minimum size when this practice is recommended? Or is there any case that this practice is recommended?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Creating 1000 tables is never the best option, so I would say you should go with one table and have indexes in it wherever required.